# Delete last 2 characters from file names in a folder using CMD

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, filenames

Hi I'm trying to replace _C which are at the end of each file name. I used 
@echo off
REN *.* ?????????.*

This works fine but the file name width could differ so what else can I do to select only the last 2 characters and rename it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use enhanced expanding of environment variable, e.g.:

```
%PATH:~0,-2%
```

would extract all but the last 2 characters of the PATH variable.
For more details, check help of set command.

And you can use FOR command to apply it on every file. Don't forget to use delayed expansion (using exclamation instead of percent) inside for cycle.

```
FOR /F %I IN ('dir *.* /B') DO (
set a=%~nI
ren %I !a:~0,-2!%~xI
)
```

Check help of FOR command for more details.

**Update:** I revised the FOR cycle and created usable batch code (including explanation comments), which works also with long filenames containing spaces. Just put this into .bat file a then run this batch inside directory, where you need to rename files.
Note: The percent needs to be doubled when used inside batch file.

```
@echo off
rem use extensions and delayed expansion
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%I IN ('dir *.* /B') DO (
rem Skip this batch
if "%0" NEQ "%%I" (
rem show renamed file
echo %%I
rem set A to filename without extension
set A=%%~nI
rem rename file to A minus last two characters with appended extension (which includes period)
ren "%%I" "!A:~0,-2!%%~xI"
))
```

Comment: I cannot understand the code. Please could you explain. I get no output when I paste this in CMD

Comment: @adr0327 The first FOR cycle was just an example, I didn't tested it directly in CMD. Now I created more useful script, which includes explanation comments.